# How to get value from a directive input field using angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.js. I have two directives in my main.js file and every directive has an input text field in the template. There is a Html page (index.html) where I want to use these directive's text fields with another input text field which is a Html input text field.

Now I want whatever input user gives in both the directive's text fields the character count should be calculated and the sum should be printed in the third text field which is a Html text field.

Code is given below:-

**Main.js file code :**

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />    

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("textbox1", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      timezone : "@"
    },
    template: "<div> <input type='text' style='background-color:orange; height=21px; width:151px;' ng-model='txtval1' ng-change='updateval()' />{{txtval1.length}} </div>"
  }
});

app.directive("textbox2", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      timezone: "@"
    },
    template: "<div> <input type='text' style='background-color:orange; height=21px; width:151px;' ng-model='txtval2' ng-change='updateval()'/>{{txtval2.length}} </div>"
  }
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.updateval = function () {
    console.log($scope.txtval1.value);
    $scope.txtThird = ($scope.txtval1.length) + ($scope.txtval2.length);
  }
});
```

---

**HTML Page Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <textbox1></textbox1>
  <textbox2></textbox2>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="txtThird"/>
</div>    

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("textbox1", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      timezone : "@",
      updateval: "&updateval"
    },
    template: "<div> <input type='text' style='background-color:orange; height=21px; width:151px;' ng-model='txtval1' ng-change=\"updateval({inputNr:'1', textval: txtval1})\" />{{txtval1.length}} </div>",
  }
});

app.directive("textbox2", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      timezone: "@",
      updateval: "&updateval"
    },
    template: "<div> <input type='text' style='background-color:orange; height=21px; width:151px;' ng-model='txtval2' ng-change=\"updateval({inputNr:'2', textval: txtval2})\" />{{txtval2.length}} </div>"
  }
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.inputValues = [
    {
      input: '1',
      value: ''
    },
    {
      input: '2',
      value: ''
    }
  ];
  $scope.updateval = function (inputNr, txtval) {
    var updatedInput = _.find($scope.inputValues, {input: inputNr});
    updatedInput.value = txtval;
    var lengthSum = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.inputValues, function(inputObj){
      lengthSum += inputObj.value.length;
    });
    console.log(lengthSum);
  }
});
```

Here is working: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/bWzLvq

Note that I used lodash.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need something this:

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <textbox length="length1"></textbox>
  <textbox length="length2"></textbox>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="txtThird"/>
  <p>Sum = {{length1+length2}}</p>
</div>   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

//script.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("textbox", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      length: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){

    },
    template: "<div> <input type='text' style='background-color:orange; height=21px; width:151px;' ng-model='txtval' ng-change='length = txtval.length'/>{{txtval.length}} </div>"
  }
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.txtThird = "some text";
  $scope.length1 = 0;
  $scope.length2 = 0;
  $scope.updateval = function () {
    console.log($scope.txtval1.value);
    $scope.txtThird = ($scope.txtval1.length) + ($scope.txtval2.length);
  }
```

You can try it on plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XE6OcQX5GOJIPMcVHWum?p=preview

Comment: Hi Sergaros. Thanks for the solution but i want the sum should be inside the third text field which has the ng-model as "txtThird" not outside this text field.

Comment: change input field in html : <input type="text" value="{{length1+length2}}">